# Unsetting PHP SImpleXML node with $variable as index

Tags: php, simplexml

I am having problems unsetting a SimpleXML node when using a variable index instead of a numerical one.

Here is my code that calls the simpleXML:

```
$highlights = new SimpleXMLElement($prj['project_xmldata']);
$node=$_POST['node'];
if(count($highlights->highlights->highlight)>0) {
   unset($highlights->highlights->highlight[$node]);
   print_r($highlights);
}
```

The contents of the print_r statement still shows the original XML data. however, if I were do unset the node using a numeric index instead of the variable `$node` I get the correct response, with the removal of the node I unset.

I've tried encapsulating the variable with double quotes as well, and made sure the $_POST['node'] is a correct value. Am I doing something wrong, or can I not put a variable inside square braces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this and let me know what it says:

```
$highlights = new SimpleXMLElement($prj['project_xmldata']); 
$node=$_POST['node']; 
if(isset($highlights->highlights->highlight[$node])) {    
    unset($highlights->highlights->highlight[$node]);    
    print_r($highlights); 
} 
else
    echo $node." = ".gettype($node);
```

Make sure that node is correct. Make sure that it is being registered as an int and not a string.

$variable[0] is different than $variable["0"]

Comment: That was it! I thought simply checking if (is_numeric) ensured it was an integer, but it was still a string. Using settype I managed to get it to work, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Rule of thumb: `is_numeric` is almost never the function you want. Don't believe me? Try `is_numeric("1.09e52")`. That said, this is another case of SimpleXML being Not Normal PHP - for a real PHP array, `$variable[0]` and `$variable["0"]` most definitely **are** the same.